# In or on which one to use? "Splurges in" vs. "splurges on"

Tags: prepositions

The difference between in and on can be seen very clearly with concrete objects like the book is in the drawer or on the table but when it comes to verbs is there any effect or difference for that matter?

> Splurges in expensive clothing or splurges on expensive clothing?

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my mind, "splurge" in this particular sense works similarly to "spend money".

We say:

> He spends money **on** expensive clothes.

Thus,

> He splurges **on** expensive clothes.

See this Ngram - "splurge in expensive" elicits no results:

[image]

Comment: Indeed.  "Don't spurge on frivolities", etc.